# Redshift queries not working with psycopg2

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I am creating a Python script to interact with schema permissions (and relative tables) on Redshift. As suggested in some other StackOverflow posts I am using psycopg2 library.

When I try to execute some simple `SELECT FROM` queries I have no problems: I can execute and see results with no issues.

Problem comes when for example I try to create a new schema or granting / revoking permissions. This kind of queries don't look like to produce any effect.

Here I show a very simple example in which I attempt to create a new schema:

```
conn_string = "dbname='{}' port='{}' host='{}' user='{}' password='{}'".format(DB_NAME, DB_PORT, DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PWD)
con = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)


sql = "CREATE SCHEMA new_schema"
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(sql)
```

But when I look into the Redshift DB I don't see any new schema called `new_schema`. Same behaviour happens when I try to run some permission grant / revoke query.

Anyone knows what is going on?

Comment: are you using the same database?

Comment: @JonScott Yes I am. Proof is that if I run some `select from` query locally with psycopg2 and on Redhsift I see the same data. Even if I change some permissions (from Redshift interface), I see the updated records both from psyocpg2 and from Redshift interface too

Comment: what happens if you run `select * from STL_DDLTEXT order by starttime desc; `  - do you see your create schema command there? if not you probably need `cur.commit()` at the end of your code.

Comment: " when I look into the Redshift DB" - what tool are you using to do that? Some tools e.g. Aginity, do not show schemas that have no objects in them. Try creating a schema and then a table in that schema, does that succeed? Or you can `SELECT * FROM pg_namespace;` to check what schemas exist.

Comment: `con.commit()` worked for creating a new schema (as reported in my example) but I'm still having problems for granting / revoking permissions as I pointed in my original question. Shall I accept the reported answer and create a new question or still is not good enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to commit the transaction.

```
con = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)

sql = "CREATE SCHEMA new_schema"
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(sql)
con.commit()
```